# customizing (dca) ordination plots in vegan

Tags: r

Hie,

Would anyone know how to customize ordination plots for "species" such that they are displayed according to a factor eg. origin.I have seen a similar example for "sites" in the dune (land-use) example. I would like to do a similar thing for species.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The community answers specific questions not provides solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as you work with sites, I would say.

Just make a vector with your factor for the species, as you have for your sites and add it to the graph..

```
plot(dca, display = 'species', type = 'n')
points(dca, dispaly = 'species', col = head)
```